# Utop can't find package "ppx_jane"

Tags: ocaml

I recently installed ocaml/opam using homebrew and prepared UTOP as in "Real World Ocaml."  In my .ocamlinit file I've added

> `#`require "ppx_jane"

Upon open, however, I get

> No such package: ppx_jane

A quick Google search didn't give any solutions and I'm wondering if anyone has run across this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install first the package :

```
opam install ppx_jane
```